# Rotation image with its canvas objects in Android

Tags: android, image-rotation

I'm using Eclipse to write android app. as navigation system.
And I'm using  "TouchImageView" class to showing the map and the map points on its canvas.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class TouchImageView extends ImageView {

Matrix matrix;

// We can be in one of these 3 states
static final int NONE = 0;
static final int DRAG = 1;
static final int ZOOM = 2;
int mode = NONE;

// Remember some things for zooming
PointF last = new PointF();
PointF start = new PointF();
float minScale = 1f;
float maxScale = 50f;
float[] m;

List<Point> AllPoints;


int viewWidth, viewHeight;
static final int CLICK = 3;
float saveScale = 1f;
protected float origWidth, origHeight;
int oldMeasuredWidth, oldMeasuredHeight;
float upx = 0, upy = 0;
public boolean ShowDrawingsOnMap;
ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;

Context context;

public int OriginalImageWidth=424;
public int OriginalImageHeight=592;
float CurrentDegree=0;

public TouchImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}


public TouchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    sharedConstructing(context);
}




private Point GetRealPos(float x, float y)
{ 
    int centerX=ImageCenter.x+xTrans;
    int centerY=ImageCenter.y+yTrans;
    double theta = CurrentDegree * Math.PI;
    theta = theta / 180;
    theta = -theta;
    double newx = (x - centerX) * Math.cos(theta) + (y - centerY) * Math.sin(theta) + centerX;
    double newy = -(x - centerX) * Math.sin(theta) + (y - centerY) * Math.cos(theta) + centerY;
    return new Point((int)newx, (int)newy);
}

boolean IfFirstInitialized=true;
@SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {   
    super.onDraw(canvas);



    // Define Paint     
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG); 
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);


    int xOrigin=AllPoints.get(0).x;
    int yOrigin=AllPoints.get(0).y; 
    int x = (int) (((xOrigin*(origWidth/424)*saveScale)+upx));
    int y = (int) (((yOrigin*(origHeight/592)*saveScale)+upy));

    if(ImageCenter==null)
    {
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 5, paint);
    }
    else
    {
        Point point = GetRealPos(x, y);
        canvas.drawCircle(point.x, point.y, 5, paint);
    }

}



boolean IfRotate=false;
Point ImageCenter=null;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void rotate(float degree) {      
    IfRotate=true;
    CurrentDegree +=degree;     

    //If ImageCenter at first time initialized
    if(ImageCenter==null)
    {
        int XmidImage=(int) (origWidth/2+upx);
        int YmidImage=(int) (origHeight/2+upy);
        ImageCenter=new Point(XmidImage, YmidImage);
    }   
    matrix.postRotate(degree, ImageCenter.x+xTrans, ImageCenter.y+yTrans);      

    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    invalidate();

}



private void sharedConstructing(Context context) {
    /*********************************/
    AllPoints=new ArrayList<Point>();
    AllPoints.add(new Point(250, 200));
    /********************************/

    super.setClickable(true);
    this.context = context;
    ShowDrawingsOnMap=true;
    mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    matrix = new Matrix();
    m = new float[9];
    setImageMatrix(matrix);
    setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);

    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            PointF curr = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());


            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:                       
                    last.set(curr);
                    start.set(last);
                    mode = DRAG;   
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mode == DRAG) {
                        float deltaX = curr.x - last.x; 
                        float deltaY = curr.y - last.y; 

                        xTrans +=(int)deltaX;
                        yTrans +=(int)deltaY;matrix.postTranslate(deltaX, deltaY);
                        last.set(curr.x, curr.y); 
                    }  
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    mode = NONE;
                    int xDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.x - start.x);
                    int yDiff = (int) Math.abs(curr.y - start.y);
                    if (xDiff < CLICK && yDiff < CLICK)
                        performClick();                        
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    mode = NONE; 
                    break;
            }

            setImageMatrix(matrix);   
            UpdateLines();
            invalidate();                 
            return true; // indicate event was handled
        }

    });         
}



int xTrans=0;
int yTrans=0;
public void UpdateLines()
{       
    matrix.getValues(m);
    upx=m[2];
    upy=m[5];
}




public void setMaxZoom(float x) {
    maxScale = x;
}


private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onScaleBegin(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        mode = ZOOM;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float mScaleFactor = detector.getScaleFactor();
        float origScale = saveScale;
        saveScale *= mScaleFactor;
        if (saveScale > maxScale) {
            saveScale = maxScale;
            mScaleFactor = maxScale / origScale;
        } else if (saveScale < minScale) {
            saveScale = minScale;
            mScaleFactor = minScale / origScale;
        }

        if (origWidth * saveScale <= viewWidth || origHeight * saveScale <= viewHeight)
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, viewWidth / 2+xTrans, viewHeight / 2+yTrans);
        else
            matrix.postScale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, detector.getFocusX(), detector.getFocusY());
        return true;
    }
}


void fixTrans() {
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y]; 

    float fixTransX = getFixTrans(transX, viewWidth, origWidth * saveScale);
    float fixTransY = getFixTrans(transY, viewHeight, origHeight * saveScale);

    if (fixTransX != 0 || fixTransY != 0) 
        matrix.postTranslate(fixTransX, fixTransY);
}

float getFixTrans(float trans, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    float minTrans, maxTrans;

    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        minTrans = 0;
        maxTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
    } else {
        minTrans = viewSize - contentSize;
        maxTrans = 0;
    }

    if (trans < minTrans)
        return -trans + minTrans;
    if (trans > maxTrans)
        return -trans + maxTrans;
    return 0;
}

float getFixDragTrans(float delta, float viewSize, float contentSize) {
    if (contentSize <= viewSize) {
        return 0;
    }
    return delta;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    viewWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    viewHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    //
    // Rescales image on rotation
    //
    if (oldMeasuredHeight == viewWidth && oldMeasuredHeight == viewHeight
            || viewWidth == 0 || viewHeight == 0)
        return;
    oldMeasuredHeight = viewHeight;
    oldMeasuredWidth = viewWidth;

    if (saveScale == 1) {
        //Fit to screen.
        float scale;

        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null || drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() == 0)
            return;
        int bmWidth = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
        int bmHeight = drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();

        Log.d("bmSize", "bmWidth: " + bmWidth + " bmHeight : " + bmHeight);

        float scaleX = (float) viewWidth / (float) bmWidth;
        float scaleY = (float) viewHeight / (float) bmHeight;
        scale = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale); 

        // Center the image            
        float redundantXSpace = (float) viewWidth - (scale * (float) bmWidth);
        float redundantYSpace = (float) viewHeight - (scale * (float) bmHeight);
        redundantYSpace /= (float) 2;
        redundantXSpace /= (float) 2;

        matrix.postTranslate(redundantXSpace, redundantYSpace);

        origWidth = viewWidth - 2 * redundantXSpace;
        origHeight = viewHeight - 2 * redundantYSpace;
        setImageMatrix(matrix);
        }
        fixTrans();
        UpdateLines();
    }

}
```

Now at first running time the point is drawing correctly, and if I rotate the map also it drawing correctly, but if I touching the image after rotation, the point doesn't show correct.

In the main activity I'm using this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

RelativeLayout myLayout;
TouchImageView img;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.MapLayout); 
    myLayout.removeAllViews();       
    img = new TouchImageView(getApplicationContext());
    img.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.map);
    myLayout.addView(img);

}

   public void RotateLeftClick(View view)
   {
      img.rotate(-90);
   }
}
```

Comment: No anybody answering me :(